# Mock imports to test function logic

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, sinon, enzyme

Lets say I have the following file.

This file imports `promiseFunction` from a library and I'd like to test the `doSomething()` function.

In particular, assert the states when the promise resolves or fails

```
// file: MyComponent.js

import promiseFunction from 'somewhere';

class MyClass extends Component {

  doSomething = () => {

    promiseFunction()
      .then((data) => {

        this.setState({...this.state, name: data.name});

      }.catch(() => {

        this.setState({...this.state, error: 'error'});

      });

  }
}
```

How do I mock the `promiseFunction` thats being imported. Or really just any function that's being imported.

```
// file: MyClass.spec.js
it('sets error in state when doSomething() is rejected', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyClass />);

  // How do I mock promiseFunction here?
  wrapper.instance().doSomething();

  expect(wrapper.state().error).toEqual('error');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) in combination with [mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn)

Here is a working example:

```
// ---- somewhere.js ----
const promiseFunction = () => {
  return Promise.resolve({name: 'name from promiseFunction'});
}
export default promiseFunction;



// ---- myclass.js ----
import * as React from 'react';
import promiseFunction from './somewhere';

export class MyClass extends React.Component {
  doSomething = () => {
    // return the Promise so the test can wait for it
    return promiseFunction()
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, name: data.name});
      }).catch(() => {
        this.setState({...this.state, error: 'error'});
      });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>This is MyClass</div>;
  }
}



// ---- myclass.test.js ----
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';
import { MyClass } from './myclass';
import * as somewhere from './somewhere';

describe('MyClass', () => {
  it('sets error in state when promiseFunction rejects', async () => {
    // set up mock for promiseFunction
    const mock = jest.spyOn(somewhere, 'default');
    mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject());

    const wrapper = shallow(<MyClass />);

    await wrapper.instance().doSomething();

    expect(wrapper.state().error).toEqual('error');

    // restore promiseFunction
    mock.mockRestore();
  });
});
```